# Route model binding not working properly on feature test laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

While doing feature test against a patch endpoint, I'm getting new instance of eloquent instead of the desired eloquent model in the controller update method. Eloquent model generated in PurchaseTest.php is not passing to the PurchaseController.php through route model binding. But the route works properly when I use it via browser.

###### web.php

```
Route::name('admin.')->middleware(['admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::name('purchases.')->prefix('/purchases')->group(function () {
        Route::patch('/{purchase}/update', 'PurchaseController@update')->name('update');
    });
});
```

###### PurchaseTest.php

```
class PurchaseTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function test_purchase_can_be_updated()
    {
        $purchase = Purchase::create([
            "item" => "tariqs item",
            "support" => "2022-09-09",
            "status" => PurchaseStatus::ACTIVE,
            "purchase_code" => "1234",
            "username" => "tariq",
            "user_id" => "1",
        ]);
        
        // $purchase model is not passing to controller through this patch request.
        $response = $this->patch(route('admin.purchases.update', compact('purchase')), [
            "item" => "tariqs item edit",
            "support" => "2022-09-09",
            "status" => PurchaseStatus::ACTIVE,
            "purchase_code" => "1234",
            "username" => "tariq",
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

###### PurchaseController.php

```
    public function update(Request $request, Purchase $purchase)
    {
        dd($purchase, $request->all());  // here $purchase is a new instance of $purchase, not the desired $purchase model.

        $input = $request->validate([
            "item" => "required|string",
            "support" => "required|date_format:Y-m-d",
            "status" => "required|string",
            "purchase_code" => "required|string",
            "username" => "required|string",
        ]);

        if ($purchase->update($input)) {
            $purchases = Purchase::where('user_id', $purchase->user_id)->get();
            return response()->json(['success' => 'true', 'msg' => __("Purchase code successfully updated."), 'embed' => view('admin.misc.purchase-list', compact('purchases'))->render()]);
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages(['error' => __('Something went wrong.')]);
    }
```

Comment: You have to use `['purchase' => $purchase->id]`, but you are saying it is not working with that? Try literally writing the full URL like `/purchases/$purchase->id/update`

Answer (score 4):

I finnaly solved this problem!

Verify if in your test, you use a `Trait WithoutMiddleware`. **If yes, then remove it!**

In My case, This was the problem! [I found here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/route-model-binding-and-phpunit).

In Laravel, model route binding is done by a `middleware`, so when i use this `Trait`, i remove all `middlewares`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do your route call like `route('admin.purchases.update', $purchase)` or `route('admin.purchases.update', $purchase->id)` without the `compact()`

Comment: I think it needs to be `['purchase' => $purchase->id]`. The second parameter for route should be an array

Comment: I've tried with `route('admin.purchases.update', $purchase)`, `route('admin.purchases.update', $purchase->id)`, `route('admin.purchases.update', ['purchase' => $purchase->id])`. But unfortunately, these don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I realized that to make model binding work, we need to have the `SubstituteBindings` middleware included in our kernel web or api middleware group. So in any case, if you removed it, your model bindings will not work.

In my case I hadn't removed it but I had a middleware that I wanted to skip it while testing and used `withoutMiddleware()` method to test my endpoint. It leads my code to skip all of the middlewares. I fixed it with specifying the exact middleware(s) that I wanted to be skipped like this:

```
$this->withoutMiddleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
])->...
```

Of course if you are working with Laravel's built-in authentication you have better alternatives like: `$this->actingAs(...)` as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) but in my case it was a little bit complicated.

Hope it helps you.